# Ralink driver installed but still no wfi

Tags: ralink

i Have install the ralink driver rt5390sta for my compaq CQ56 laptop. But even after installing the drive, it doesn't show up at all. the driver install successfully. How do i make the wireless card(chipset) communicate with ubuntu.

Comment: Start by sharing what exact wireless card you have. Post the relevant output of `lspci -nn` (internal/integrated) or `lsusb` (USB). Also, what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)

Comment: 12.04 LTS verison of ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

I own an HP650 which came with preinstalled SUSE Linux Enterprise Novell.

The wireless card on this laptop is the Ralink 539a. The driver/module for this wlan card loaded by the kernel is the rt2800pci. The problem ofcourse is that by default they do not work or if they work its unstable and practicly unusable. After reading many threads and following a lot of different lines to build the 2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO the result was never successful failing either at the build with >make returning an error for Antenna being changed to y for yes or the driver not starting the wlan0 interface if the Antenna switch remains n for off.

Later I found a bug report and exchange specificly for the Ralink 539a where the solution to the problem was finallzy found. Essentially 1. Download latest Compat-Wireless drivers from http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Download/stable/#compat-wireless_3.6_stable_releases 2. Unpack to a directory 3. cd to directory 4. sudo make 5. sudo make install 6 reboot your computer 7. make sure the wireless card light/led is on by using the wireless on/off button....

That did it for me. A note I also read is that any time the kernel or drivers are updated the old rt2800pci driver/module gets unpacked and thus the wireless gets back to not working .... So the same procedure of make and make install to overwrite with the compat.wireless drivers that work is to be done...

Good luck